# Using JQuery in Laravel to create sortable table

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel and trying to create a simple sortable table using JQuery.

I have the following in my view:

```
<table id="dtBasicExample" class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Submission ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Advisor ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Advisor Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Advisor Email</th>
        <th scope="col">Link</th>
        <th scope="col">Employer Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Received Date</th>
        <th scope="col">Plan Renewal Date</th>
        <th scope="col">Status</th>
        <th scope="col">Copy</th>
        <th scope="col">Delete</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>



     @foreach($plans as $plan)
            <tr>
                <td> {{$plan->id}}</td>
                <td> {{$plan->advisor_id}}</td>
                <td> {{$plan->advisor->name}}</td>
                <td> {{$plan->advisor->email}}</td>
                <td><a href="/basicinfo/{{$plan->id}}/edit">Click Here</a></td>
                <td>{{$plan->employer_name}}</td>
                <td>{{$plan->updated_at}}</td>
                <td>{{$plan->medical_plan_renewal_date}}</td>
                <td>{{$plan->status}}</td>
                <td><a href="copy/{{$plan->id}}">Copy</a></td>
                <td><a href="delete/{{$plan->id}}">Delete</a></td>
    @endforeach
        </tr>

    </tbody>


  </table>
```

I have the following in my app.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dtBasicExample").DataTable();
    $(".dataTables_length").addClass("bs-select");
});
```

I have the following in my app.css file:

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting:before,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc:before,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled:before,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc:before,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled:before {
bottom: .5em;
}
```

I imagine I am wrong on where to put the JS and/or CSS.  My understanding is the bootstrap.js file pulls in JQuery and the app.js file pulls in the bootstrap.js file.  Also, my app.css (in public folder) is highlighted red when I open it.

Comment: Have you pulled in the Datatables library into your project? You'll need to do that as well. The red `.css` file *could* be due to what your editor thinks are invalid selectors/values.

Comment: thanks, i didn't pull in the Datatables library.  The error I am getting in app.css doesn't make a lot of sense.  I am using VSCode.  I opened the file but did not modify it.  The first line is showing an error with "@charset".  This line:  @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito);@charset "UTF-8";